# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im currently learning Python and im not so good in coding and stuff, but i have a problem, i get all the time the error `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'` and i don't know what that means, i think its summething that the object NoneType not  a attribute 'html' has. Im using [discord.py](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) the newest version and [chat-exporter](https://pypi.org/project/chat-exporter/). I already read the Documentation but i didn't found any solution to my problem.

Here is the code:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role(MANAGEMENT_ROLE_ID)
async def archive(ctx: commands.Context): 
    transcript = await chat_exporter.export(
        ctx.channel,
        tz_info="UTC",
        military_time=True, 
        bot=client
        )

    if transcript is None:
        return

    print(transcript)
    transcript_file = discord.File(
        io.BytesIO(transcript.encode()),
        filename=f"transcript-{ctx.channel.name}",
    )

    await ctx.send(file=transcript_file)
```

and thats the full log of it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Discord\discord Bots\derzockereckenbot 2.0\main.py", line 136, in archive
    transcript = await chat_exporter.export(
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chat_exporter\chat_exporter.py", line 50, in export
    return (
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'
```

Can you please help me

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback of the error. There is something missing after `return (`

Comment: Hello, i check again and it is the full Log there is nothing missing

Comment: It looks like a potential issue with the library you're using (unless you're passing arguments wrong, which you would have to check docs to make sure).

Comment: I found now the error, needed to downgrade the version of chat-exporter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: downgrade your chat-exporter version